# Posts for a fence line raised garden

Tags: raised-beds

I am going to build a raised garden along a fence. According to this YouTube  tutorial: [Building a raised garden bed - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YASRTcbJ4Y), the holes are dug up so that the posts can be fixated to the ground. When I watched it, I was wondering if installing posts in the ground was necessary. I will use the posts to attach siding walls to them but is it necessary to install posts in the ground?

Thanks,

Comment: Putting posts into ground will make whole structure more robust but you won't be able to easily change location of raised bad (especially if you make concrete foundations like that guy in the video). Also, if you make raised bed with one side attached to fence (and if raised bed is too wide), it may be hard to reach/work around plants.

Comment: If you're making a four-sided raised bed, don't put it directly against the fence. If your fence is wooden, this will cause both the bed and the fence to rot prematurely; if it's vinyl, then you'll rot the bed prematurely. You also don't want to put the soil directly up against the fence, for the same reason as above. You need to leave at least enough room to pull weeds. Personally, I'd install bricks on a layer of sand (so that the bricks are at the original ground level) between bed and fence. This will reduce weeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, posts are not needed at all.  In fact, those wooden sides or any type of structure is not needed for raised beds.  This is just for looks.

Not sure what you are trying to do but do not use your fence to hold soil, to hold lumber holding soil.  Fences are not made to hold soil.  Any moisture being held against the wood will rot that wood sooner than later.

The only benefit to making these lumber raised beds is for looks.  Seriously.  Look very nice.  Keep air between that fence and any soil, mulch, lumber.  Or your fence will rot.

I always 'raise' my beds. No matter the type of soil.  I've built raised beds like this with gravel walks and installed drainage.  But I would never do this for my own gardens.
[image: raised beds]
[image: raised beds]
[image: raised beds caliche clay]